# How to allign a page, when browser restored down

Tags: visualforce

I am using a Output label and a custom Field in VF page. But the problem is when browser is restoring down, the page allignment doesn't look good.

**VF Page:**

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" columns="2">
                  <apex:inputField value="{!mpgcObj.MPG_Code__c}"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!mpgcObj.MPG_Description__c}"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!mpgcObj.MPG_Pricing_Option__c}"/>

                  <apex:outputPanel>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;               
                    <apex:outputLabel >Specific Discount</apex:outputLabel> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <apex:selectList id="discountPrice" value="{!selectedId}" size="1" multiselect="false" rendered="{!isVisible}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!pickList}"/>
                    </apex:selectList> 
                </apex:outputPanel> 

                  <apex:inputField value="{!mpgcObj.Is_Active__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

**I have added a picture, how it looks like, when I browser got restored down.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using an `apex:outputPanel` with lots of `&nbsp;` to align you elements, you should try using an `apex:pageBlockSectionItem`.

This will combine your two child elements (`apex:outputPanel` and `apex:selectList`) into a single element that only takes up one column on the page.

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputLabel >Specific Discount</apex:outputLabel> 
    <apex:selectList id="discountPrice" value="{!selectedId}" size="1" multiselect="false" rendered="{!isVisible}">
         <apex:selectOptions value="{!pickList}"/>
     </apex:selectList> 
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Alternatively you can use the label attribute on the `apex:selectList` component rather than using an `apex:outputLabel` to display it, in which case you don't need the `apex:pageBlockSectionItem` and can put place it directly after your `apex:inputField` components.

```
<apex:selectList id="discountPrice" label="Specific Discount" value="{!selectedId}" size="1" multiselect="false" rendered="{!isVisible}">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!pickList}"/>
 </apex:selectList>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a [apex:pageBlockSectionItem](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm) rather than an [apex:outputPanel](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm). The pageBlockSection only takes up one column in one row

```
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Specific Discount"/>
        <apex:selectList id="discountPrice" value="{!selectedId}" size="1" multiselect="false" rendered="{!isVisible}">
             <apex:selectOptions value="{!pickList}"/>
         </apex:selectList> 
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

**FYI:** because you are using `rendered="{!isVisible}"` on the `apex:selectList`, the label will still be visible when `{!isVisible}` evaluates to false. If you want the field and label to disappear then add the rendered attribute to the `apex:pageBlockSectionItem` element